# Postback Occurring Multiple Times

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, devexpress, postback

I need some guidance as I cant seem to work out what's wrong.

My form page (includes SharePoint wizard control) is doing a postback on submit 3 times. Why is it posting back 3 times? Why not once?

Note that we are using two DevExpress AspxGridView grids binding to a object data source (not sure if this is related to the issue).

I have the following markup:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" ID="ValidationSummary1" />
<br />
<asp:Wizard runat="server" ID="wizRequest" ActiveStepIndex="0" OnNextButtonClick="wizRequest_NextButtonClick" DisplaySideBar="false">
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:WizardStep runat="server" ID="wsSection1">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><%= Localization.GetRequest("Section1") %></legend>
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <th><%= Localization.GetRequest("Title") %></th>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtTitle" Width="95%" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTitle" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" Text="*" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><%= Localization.GetRequest("Summary") %></th>
                        <td colspan="5">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtSummary" Width="95%" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="3" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvSummary" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSummary" Text="*" /></td>
                    </tr>

...
```

And the following code:

```
        [ToolboxItemAttribute(false)]
        public partial class RequestWizardWebPart : WebPart
        {
[System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Assert, UnmanagedCode = true)]
            public RequestWizardWebPart()
            {
            }
            protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
            {
                base.OnInit(e);
                InitializeControl();
            }

            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                AddSupportingDocumentControl();

                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    LoadControlsLocalizedText();
                    LoadLists();
                    LoadRequest();
                }
            }

    ...
```

Comment: Probably AJAX calls behind the scenes. Monitor the network traffic via your browser tools and see what's being sent.

Comment: +1 for AJAX. A likely suspect

Comment: [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is your friend :)

Comment: Have you added a break point and stepped through the code?

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Request.Form["_EVENTTARGET"]** expression to know which control invokes a postback and why.